# SELECT inside a COUNT

Tags: sql

I would like to embed a SELECT inside a COUNT, but I can't find any examples.

```
#pseudosql
SELECT a AS current_a, COUNT(*) AS b,
   COUNT( SELECT FROM t WHERE a = current_a AND c = 'const' ) as d,
   from t group by a order by b desc
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get multiple counts with one SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789396/how-to-get-multiple-counts-with-one-sql-query)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You don't really need a sub-select:

```
SELECT a, COUNT(*) AS b,
   SUM( CASE WHEN c = 'const' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as d,
   from t group by a order by b desc
```

Comment: +1 This addresses the OP's specific query in a more efficient way. I would use `IF()` instead of `CASE` since there are only 2 states, but removing the sub-query is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 31):

You can move the count() inside your sub-select:

```
SELECT a AS current_a, COUNT(*) AS b,
   ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t WHERE a = current_a AND c = 'const' ) as d,
   from t group by a order by b desc
```

Comment: So, Select inside a count is a syntax error in sql?

Answer (score 2):

Use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t WHERE a = current_a AND c = 'const' ) as d`.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT a AS current_a, COUNT(*) AS b,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t WHERE a = current_a AND c = 'const' ) as d
   from t group by a order by b desc
```