# MySQL Select Distinct Count

Tags: mysql

```
+----------+----------+
| user_id  | video_id |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |    1     |
|        1 |    1     |
|        1 |    2     |
|        2 |    1     |
|        2 |    2     |
+----------+----------+
```

I have a table setup similar to the one above. I would like to return a total count from my query.

For each `user_id` they need to have a `DISTINCT video_id`. So above, `user_id = 1` would have 2 unique video_id's and `user_id = 2` would have 2 unique video_id's. This would make the total 4. I'm not sure the best way to organize my query to achieve the desired result.

Basically for each user_id, I need something like, `COUNT(DISTINCT video_id)`

I would like the final result just to return total count of everything.

Comment: People interested in counting distinct rows on several columns (e.g. with wildcard `*`) should check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20620693/812102).

Answer (score 92, accepted):

If you want to get the total count for each user, then you will use:

```
select user_id, count(distinct video_id)
from data
group by user_id;
```

Then if you want to get the total video_ids then you will wrap this inside of a subquery:

```
select sum(cnt) TotalVideos
from
(
  select user_id, count(distinct video_id) cnt
  from data
  group by user_id
) d
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26e8e/3) of both.

The first query will give you the result of `2` for each `user_id` and then to get the total of all distinct video_ids you sum the count.

Comment: @bluefeet On a side note, what if we have another column say audio_id and we want to get count of it too in the same query?

Comment: In reference to your this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789396/how-to-get-multiple-counts-with-one-sql-query/12789493#12789493 but I need to select it as distinct like above.

Comment: @IrfanAhmed Off hand I'm not sure. I'd say post a new question with your requirements so it could be answered.

Answer (score 3):

```
select user_id, count(distinct video_id) from TABLE group by user_id;
```

Comment: Is there a way to return just a total count rather than each users count?

Comment: Yes, and I believe bluefeet answered that very well for you.

Answer (score 2):

For total count...

```
select distinct count(video_id) from Table
where...
group...
```

Comment: I know it's old but just for correctness the above will not return total count of unique values as asked in the original question.

Comment: This will not return distinct - but will return count - this is an erroneous answer

Answer (score 2):

For now a total count of unique user_id, video_id pairs can be calculated with the following query

```
select count(distinct user_id, video_id) from table;
```