# count distinct records (all columns) not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count

what's proper syntax for

```
count (distinct *) from t1
```

I am getting he following error:

> [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'distinct'.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
select count(*)
from
(
   select distinct * from your_table
) x
```

Comment: worked, thanks I will accept as soon as ten minutes pass by. Is there a particular reason why this works and the original one didn't, other than its how the syntax is supposed to be ?

Comment: @EduardoDennis: sql-syntax - select count(*) from table ... and table is select distinct * from innertable

Comment: @EduardoDennis: You need to specify one column when you use `distinct`: `select count(distinct col1) ...` If you want distinct records of all columns you have to use a subquery as I did.

Comment: May be advisable to list out the columns if this is going to be re-used.

Comment: What's the `) x` on line 5 do?

Comment: it names the subquery: `(subquery) alias_for_subquery`