# Handling null values on hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a column in hive with type double, but some of the rows are NULL when I do:

```
select columnA from table;
```

now, if I run the following, I get 0 for both queries:

```
select count(*) from table where columnA = "NULL";
select count(*) from table where columnA = NULL;
```

how can I count the rows in my table which are NULL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct query is:

```
select count(*) from table where columnA is null;
```

Comment: Olaf, do you know how I could do this for every column in a table? The table has a large number of columns and I'd rather not have to run one query for every single column.

Comment: @user2932774: I have not tried that in Hive, but in a standard SQL you can use "case". See for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789396/how-to-get-multiple-counts-with-one-sql-query

Comment: but what does columnA = null stand for? It won't throw an exception, which shows "columnA = null" at least is working normally.

Answer (score 5):

In Hive, count(*) counts all rows and count(columnA) will only count rows where columnA is non-NULL. If you would like to do multiple columns you could write the query as:

```
select count(*)-count(columnA), count(*)-count(columnB) from table;
```

and get the number of null values in each column. 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF