# Getting Distinct Value Counts Across Multiple Fields/Tables in One MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table called `visits` which contains the following
`link_id`, `id`, `browser`, `country`, `referer`

Now, this basically records visits of a certain link and inserts the browser, country and referer of whomever visted that link in a database

Now I need to show statistics for each link

I used the following query to get me all the browsers

`SELECT browser, COUNT(browser) FROM visits GROUP BY browser`

Which produced something like

`Browser             Count(Browser)
 Internet Explorer | 5
 Chrome            | 3`

Now this worked as expected for browsers only but I'm looking for a way to count all occurrences of `referers`, `browsers` and `countries` in one single query.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what results you want.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789396/how-to-get-multiple-counts-with-one-sql-query

Comment: @KodleeYin . . . It is quite unclear whether this question is a duplicate of that one.  There is not enough information about what the OP wants.

Comment: You really need to put the result you want into your question. Without it we can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

To count multiple, different occurence counts of values in the DB can very easily be done in just one query.

Keep in mind, the column header in `SELECT COUNT(tablename)` returns only one column, with only one numeric value.  For every distinct value (from the `GROUP BY` clause), you have two columns: Value, Count.  To count for different fields, you'll need three: Field, Value, Count, and if you want to count different fields in different tables, you'll need four: Table, Field, Value, Count.

Observe how I am using `UNION` below for two different tables:

```
SELECT
        "Table1" AS TableName,
        "Field1" AS Field,
        Field1 AS Value, 
        COUNT(Field1) AS COUNT
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY Value
UNION
SELECT
        "Table2" as TableName,
        "Field2" as Field,
        Field2 as Value,
        COUNT(Field2) AS COUNT
    FROM Table2
    GROUP BY Value
```

You'll notice I need to use aliases: `"Table2" as TableName`, this is because the `UNION`'d columns ought to have matching column headers.

So you can visualize what this returns, take a look:

```
+-------------------+----------------+----------+--------+
| TableName         | Field          | Value    | COUNT  |
+-------------------+----------------+----------+--------+
| ItemFee           | PaymentType    |          |    228 |
| ItemFee           | PaymentType    | All      |      1 |
| ItemFee           | PaymentType    | PaidOnly |      1 |
| Person            | Presenter      |          | 692258 |
| Person            | Presenter      | N        |    590 |
| Person            | Presenter      | Y        |   8103 |
+-------------------+----------------+----------+--------+
```