# SQL - How to use more COUNT on many tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I need to get the COUNT of each `id_prevadzka` IN 4 tables:

First I tried:

```
SELECT
    p.id_prevadzka,
    COUNT(pv.id_prevadzka) AS `vytoce_pocet`,
    COUNT(pn.id_prevadzka) AS `navstevy_pocet`,
    COUNT(pa.id_prevadzka) AS `akcie_pocet`,
    COUNT(ps.id_prevadzka) AS `servis_pocet`
FROM shop_prevadzky p
LEFT JOIN shop_prevadzky_vytoce pv ON (pv.id_prevadzka = p.id_prevadzka)
LEFT JOIN shop_prevadzky_navstevy pn ON (pn.id_prevadzka = p.id_prevadzka)
LEFT JOIN shop_prevadzky_akcie pa ON (pa.id_prevadzka = p.id_prevadzka)
LEFT JOIN shop_prevadzky_servis ps ON (ps.id_prevadzka = p.id_prevadzka)
GROUP BY p.id_prevadzka
```

But this returned the same number for `vytoce_pocet`, `navstevy_pocet`, `akcie_pocet` and `servis_pocet` - and it was the number, what was the COUNT in `shop_prevadzky_vytoce`.

Then I tried ([as is answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12789493/1631551)):

```
SELECT
    p.*,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pv.id_prevadzka IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `vytoce_pocet`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pn.id_prevadzka IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `navstevy_pocet`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pa.id_prevadzka IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `akcie_pocet`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ps.id_prevadzka IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `servis_pocet`
FROM shop_prevadzky p
LEFT JOIN shop_prevadzky_vytoce pv ON (pv.id_prevadzka = p.id_prevadzka)
LEFT JOIN shop_prevadzky_navstevy pn ON (pn.id_prevadzka = p.id_prevadzka)
LEFT JOIN shop_prevadzky_akcie pa ON (pa.id_prevadzka = p.id_prevadzka)
LEFT JOIN shop_prevadzky_servis ps ON (ps.id_prevadzka = p.id_prevadzka)
WHERE p.cis_status = 1
GROUP BY p.id_prevadzka
ORDER BY p.prevadzka_nazov
```

But it returned the same results as is in the first example.

Whats wrong in my second query? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

To understand well, this could be test data in my tables:

*shop_prevadzky:*

```
id_prevadzka
1
2
```

*shop_prevadzky_vytoce:*

```
id | id_prevadzka
1  | 1
2  | 1
3  | 1
4  | 1
5  | 2
```

*shop_prevadzky_navstevy:*

```
id | id_prevadzka
1  | 1
2  | 1
```

*shop_prevadzky_akcie:*

```
id | id_prevadzka
1  | 2
```

*shop_prevadzky_servis:*

```
id | id_prevadzka
```

And the query should return:

```
id_prevadzka | vytoce_pocet | navstevy_pocet | akcie_pocet | servis_pocet
1              4              2                0             0
2              1              0                1             0
```

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing some sample data. I can say that your inclusion of `p.*` could prove to be very problematic here. Perhaps narrow that down to the fields from `p` that you actually need and include them in your `GROUP BY` statement if they aren't being aggregated by a formula otherwise you are going to get oddball results. Can you include some sample data for the tables so we can better understand the schema and also include your expected results form the query.

Comment: I also guessed and added the `MySQL` tag since it's the only DBMS that would allow you to exclude non-aggregated fields in your GROUP BY (which may be what's leading to the issues you are facing). Any other DBMS would throw an error if you tried to submit this SQL.

Comment: @JNevill Sorry, it takes more time, now I added simple example data with expecting result.

Comment: Thanks, @Legionar. I saw that a minute after I threw that comment out there. Thank you! It looks like Juan Carlos is all over it below.

Comment: Your query is fine,I think you are confused about what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try count distinct as in:

Using your data sample

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f63cd/3)**

```
SELECT
    p.id_prevadzka,
    COUNT(distinct pv.id) AS `vytoce_pocet`,
    COUNT(distinct pn.id) AS `navstevy_pocet`,
    COUNT(distinct pa.id) AS `akcie_pocet`,
    COUNT(distinct ps.id) AS `servis_pocet`
FROM shop_prevadzky p
LEFT JOIN shop_prevadzky_vytoce pv ON (pv.id_prevadzka = p.id_prevadzka)
LEFT JOIN shop_prevadzky_navstevy pn ON (pn.id_prevadzka = p.id_prevadzka)
LEFT JOIN shop_prevadzky_akcie pa ON (pa.id_prevadzka = p.id_prevadzka)
LEFT JOIN shop_prevadzky_servis ps ON (ps.id_prevadzka = p.id_prevadzka)
GROUP BY p.id_prevadzka
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| id_prevadzka | vytoce_pocet | navstevy_pocet | akcie_pocet | servis_pocet |
|--------------|--------------|----------------|-------------|--------------|
|            1 |            4 |              2 |           0 |            0 |
|            2 |            1 |              0 |           1 |            0 |
```

Comment: @Jhon  because if same `id` appeear twice you want `count = 2`

Comment: Sorry, I'm assuming that the id is a primary key in this case.  This should work if you are counting the primary key (which you should be doing).  I've edited the above to reflect this.

Comment: I try to create a fiddle but server isnt workin right now to test it. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f63cd/1

Comment: Lol, is running again, you can check your query result now :)

Comment: Sorry for the big edit. You have the right approach.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Juan Carlos!

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are joining all tables and created a cartesian product

```
shop_prevadzky x _vytoce x _navstevy x _akcie x _servis
```

You may want

```
SELECT
    p.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(id_prevadzka) FROM shop_prevadzky_vytoce s WHERE s.id_prevadzka = p.id_prevadzka) AS `vytoce_pocet`,
    (SELECT COUNT(id_prevadzka) FROM shop_prevadzky_navstevy s WHERE s.id_prevadzka = p.id_prevadzka) AS `navstevy_pocet`,
    (SELECT COUNT(id_prevadzka) FROM shop_prevadzky_akcie s WHERE s.id_prevadzka = p.id_prevadzka) AS `akcie_pocet`,
    (SELECT COUNT(id_prevadzka) FROM shop_prevadzky_servis s WHERE s.id_prevadzka = p.id_prevadzka) AS `servis_pocet`
FROM shop_prevadzky p
```

Also you can do the same with subquerys

```
SELECT
    p.*,
    COALESCE(vytoce_count, 0) as vytoce_count,
    COALESCE(navstevy_count, 0) as navstevy_count,
    COALESCE(akcie_count, 0) as akcie_count,
    COALESCE(servis_count, 0) as servis_count
FROM shop_prevadzky p
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT id_prevadzka, COUNT(id_prevadzka) vytoce_count
            FROM shop_prevadzky_vytoce s 
            WHERE s.id_prevadzka = p.id_prevadzka) AS vytoce
       ON p.id_prevadzka = vytoce.id_prevadzka

LEFT JOIN  (SELECT id_prevadzka, COUNT(id_prevadzka) navstevy_count
            FROM shop_prevadzky_navstevy s 
            WHERE s.id_prevadzka = p.id_prevadzka) AS navstevy
       ON p.id_prevadzka = navstevy.id_prevadzka

LEFT JOIN  (SELECT id_prevadzka, COUNT(id_prevadzka) akcie_count
            FROM shop_prevadzky_akcie s 
            WHERE s.id_prevadzka = p.id_prevadzka) AS akcie
       ON p.id_prevadzka = akcie.id_prevadzka

LEFT JOIN  (SELECT id_prevadzka, COUNT(id_prevadzka) servis_count
            FROM shop_prevadzky_servis s 
            WHERE s.id_prevadzka = p.id_prevadzka) AS servis
       ON p.id_prevadzka = servis.id_prevadzka
```

Comment: Yes, thats true. Could it be done with one SELECT without using subqueries?

Comment: Thats not what a cartesian product is.

Answer (score 0):

What about this way:

```
SELECT
p.id_prevadzka,
(Select COUNT(pv.id_prevadzka) from shop_prevadzky_vytoce pv where pv.id_prevadzka = p.id_prevadzka) AS `vytoce_pocet`,
(Select COUNT(pn.id_prevadzka) from shop_prevadzky_navstevy pn where pn.id_prevadzka = p.id_prevadzka) AS `navstevy_pocet`,
(Select COUNT(pa.id_prevadzka) from shop_prevadzky_akcie pa Where pa.id_prevadzka = p.id_prevadzka) AS `akcie_pocet`,
(Select COUNT(ps.id_prevadzka) from shop_prevadzky_servis ps Where ps.id_prevadzka = p.id_prevadzka) AS `servis_pocet`
FROM shop_prevadzky p
WHERE p.cis_status = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to do this as a single query?  Why not something like:

```
select count(*) from foo;
select count(*) from bar;
```

OR

```
select 'FOO_COUNT' as table_name, count(*) as cnt from foo
union all 
select 'BAR_COUNT' as table_name, count(*) as cnt from bar
;
```

Comment: Because it need to be GROUP BY id_prevadzka. I don't need COUNT of all rows in all tables.