# SQL Count multiple columns based

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have 2 data tables I need to query data from

```
Machine_ID  Machine_name
101         Computer1
202         Computer2
303         Computer3
404         Computer4
```

Second table:

```
Machine_ID Event_ID Event_date
101        1        03/15/2016
101        1        03/14/2016
101        2        03/15/2016
101        1        03/13/2016
102        1        03/15/2016
102        2        03/15/2016
102        1        03/14/2016
103        2        03/15/2016
103        2        03/14/2016
104        1        03/15/2016
```

I need the output of the query to be in one line and contain information:

```
Machine_ID, 
Machine_Name, 
Count(Machine_ID) where Event_ID='1'
Count(Machine_ID) where Event_ID='2'
```

I have tried numerous ways to write the query but am at a loss for the correct syntax.

This does not work but will give an idea of what I'm going for:

```
Select M.Machine_ID, M.Machine_Name, 
count(Machine_ID) where E.Event_ID='1' and Machine_ID='101', 
count(Machine_ID) where E.Event_ID='2' and Machine_ID='101' 
from Machines M 
join Events E on M.Machine_ID = E.Machine_ID
```

The output from this based in the given data should be:

```
101 Computer1 3 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get multiple counts with one SQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789396/how-to-get-multiple-counts-with-one-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    M.Machine_ID, 
    M.Machine_Name, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN E.Event_ID='1' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Event1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN E.Event_ID='2' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Event2
FROM Machines M 
    JOIN Events E 
    ON M.Machine_ID = E.Machine_ID
GROUP BY M.Machine_ID, M.Machine_Name
```

Comment: You don't need to specify ELSE NULL. This is default behavior for CASE statement.

Comment: Procedural programmers sometimes freak out because of all the coding standards requiring and `else`. I often include just to keep them happy even though I would prefer to omit it most of the time.

Comment: @ConsiderMe Since it doesn't hurt anything, I prefer to be explicit where possible rather than leave any decisions to the computer.  Computers do dumb things in the absence of instruction.  But it's just a personal preference/opinion.

Comment: But there is an instrunction, just not explicitly wrote by the user. Anyways, it's a matter of preference I guess as you've said :)

Comment: Well this worked for what I wanted to do. I just never considered using a case statement for doing the counting.

Answer (score -1):

Use a conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    M.Machine_ID, 
    M.Machine_Name, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN E.Event_ID = '1' THEN 1 END) AS Event1_cnt,
    SUM(CASE WHEN E.Event_ID = '2' THEN 1 END) AS Event2_cnt
FROM 
    Machines M 
    JOIN Events E 
      ON M.Machine_ID = E.Machine_ID
GROUP BY 
    M.Machine_ID, M.Machine_Name
```

If you want to limit the output only to one machine id (for instance: `101`) add a following line before `GROUP BY`:

```
WHERE M.Machine_ID = '101'
```

Also, it seems like a bad idea to store `ID` as a string. Consider changing your data type to integer or anything alike.

Comment: Could the person who downvoted this answer add a comment on why has this action been taken?