# Multiple COUNT SELECTS from the same table in one

Tags: mysql

how to do multiple `COUNT(*) SELECTS` from the same table in one ...

```
$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM content_form WHERE read_flag = 0 ";  
$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM content_form WHERE read_flag = 1 "; 
$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM content_form WHERE read_flag = 0 ";
```

Comment: Query 1 and 3 are exactly equivalent. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789396/how-to-get-multiple-counts-with-one-sql-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT read_flag,count(read_flag) as cnt FROM content_form WHERE read_flag IN (0,1,....) GROUP BY read_flag
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    $query = "SELECT sum(Case when read_flag=0 then 1 else 0 end) as ReadFlag0Cnt, 
                     sum(Case when read_flag=1 then 1 else 0 end) as ReadFlag1Cnt
              FROM content_form";
You can use case statement
```

Comment: @AkshayBhat - 
Instead of COUNT, it should be SUM -

$query = "SELECT SUM(Case when read_flag=0 then 1 else 0 end) as ReadFlag0Cnt, 
                 SUM(Case when read_flag=1 then 1 else 0 end) as ReadFlag1Cnt
          FROM content_form";

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
$query = "select (SELECT count(*) FROM content_form WHERE read_flag = 0) 
as flag0, (SELECT count(*) FROM content_form WHERE read_flag = 1) as flag1,
(SELECT count(*) FROM content_form WHERE read_flag = 0) as flag0) from content_form";
```