# Multiple Counts in MYSQL query

Tags: mysql

I would like to count a specific database column with TWO different count criteria so i can calculate a percentage

For example lets same the database column is called Latency, and the data in the column contains the number of seconds.

I would like to count the number of Latency messages > 50 seconds but also the TOTAL number of Latency messages in the same query ( i.e. > 0 seconds)

My current query for > 50 seconds is as follows

```
select COUNT(*) from table WHERE date = 20180701 and CAST(Latency As Signed) > 50
```

How would i include counts > 0 seconds in the same query ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get multiple counts with one SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789396/how-to-get-multiple-counts-with-one-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(Latency As Signed) > 50 THEN 1 END) AS latency,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(Latency As Signed) > 0  THEN 1 END) AS total,
    100.0 * COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(Latency As Signed) > 50 THEN 1 END) /
            COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(Latency As Signed) > 0  THEN 1 END) AS percentage
FROM table
WHERE date = 20180701;
```

Comment: Going one step further , is it possible to calculate a "percentage" of total / latency in the sql statement ?

Comment: @John Just take the ratios of the two conditional counts (I think).

Answer (score 0):

This maybe helpful to you, @John, [How to get multiple counts with one SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789396/how-to-get-multiple-counts-with-one-sql-query) It uses count together with aggregate functions in order to target multiple count function in one query..

Comment: Hi Aries, when you find a duplicate like this it's better to just flag the question as a duplicate instead (use the `flag` link underneath the question tags).

Comment: Thanks for that, @Nick I'll look for that helpful tip.. :)