# PHP - How can I foreach an SQL Statement by conditional where

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I want to know how can I foreach a sql count statement depending on its status. When I tried to echo it, all statuses turned into number 1. I want to put it inside a loop instead of doing the statement five times.

```
<?php
$statuses = array("In-process", "Approved", "Draft", "Approved" , "Rejected"); 

foreach ($statuses as $stat) {  
    $stmt = $db->prepare(
        "SELECT COUNT(status) FROM `m2_exception_requests`
         WHERE created_by= ? and   status = ?"
    ) or die($db->error);  

    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user_id , $stat);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->store_result(); 

    if  ($stat = 'In-process') {
        $Inprocess1 =  $result;
    }
    if  ($stat = 'Approved') {
        $Approved1 =  $result;
    }
    if  ($stat = 'Draft') {
        $Draft1 = $result;
    }      
}
```

Comment: Why the PDO tag.  Looks like you are using MySqli?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get multiple counts with one SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789396/how-to-get-multiple-counts-with-one-sql-query)

Comment: Maybe you can do it with ONE select using "case"?

Comment: Check the type of equals you use in things like `$stat = 'In-process'` - this is assignment and not equal to (`==`)

Comment: @NigelRen did that too but nothing happens...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a dynamic and SQL Injection safe solution:

This will use the `IN` and the `GROUP BY` clauses to generate your results.

```
$statuses = array("In-process", "Approved", "Draft", "Approved" , "Rejected");

$clause = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($statuses), '?')); //create your question marks
$types = 's' . str_repeat('s', count($statuses)); //create you bindings

$query = "SELECT COUNT(status) 
  FROM `m2_exception_requests`
  WHERE created_by = ? 
  AND status IN($clause)
  GROUP BY status";

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param($types, $user_id, ...$statuses);
$stmt->execute();
$resArr = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if(!$resArr) exit('No rows');
var_export($resArr);
$stmt->close();
```

Good luck!

Comment: it works but can I ask how can i echo it?  I tried working with `implode(" ",$resArr[1]);` however if its null the array adjust

Comment: That should have displayed an array for you.  When you reference `$resArr[1]` you are saying that you want to implode the `[1]` element of the array.  You probably need to change it to: `echo implode(' ', $resArr);` that way you are referencing the entire array.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `GROUP BY` to get count of record in each status; below is simple SQL query; you convert it in Parameter bindings;

```
SELECT status, COUNT(status) FROM `m2_exception_requests` WHERE `created_by` = ? AND `status` IN ("In-process", "Approved", "Draft", "Approved1" , "Rejected") GROUP BY `status`
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
<?php
$statuses = array("In-process", "Approved", "Draft", "Approved1" , "Rejected"); 

$statusVal = [];
foreach ($statuses as $stat) {  
    $stmt = $db->prepare(
        "SELECT COUNT(status) FROM 
            `m2_exception_requests`
            WHERE created_by= ? 
            and   status = ?"
    ) or die($db->error);  

    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user_id , $stat);
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $stmt->rowCount(); 

    $statusVal[$stat] = $count;
}

var_dump($statusVal);
```

you will get values like this

```
[
    "In-process" => 1,
    "Approved" => 2,
    "Draft" => 3,
    "Approved1" => 4,
    "Rejected" => 5
]
```

Comment: I dont know why it is showing `array(5) { ["In-process"]=> bool(true) ["Approved"]=> bool(true) ["Draft"]=> bool(true) ["Approved1"]=> bool(true) ["Rejected"]=> bool(true) }`

Comment: are you using PDO?

Comment: im sorry im using mysqli