# how to calculate ratio of two counts using sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table (shown below) where I need to calculate percent of toys that have price lower than 10. How do I do it in sql?

```
toy price
a   9
b   12
c   15
d   5
```

Comment: This answer seems to help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789396/how-to-get-multiple-counts-with-one-sql-query

select count(*), sum(case when price <= 10 then 1 else 0 end) AS cheapProductCount from toys group by toys

Answer (score 2):

A simple method uses `avg()`:

```
select avg( (price < 10)::int ) as ratio
from toys;
```

If you want a percentage between 0 and 100, then multiply by 100.

Comment: Thanks! what if I have to use counts?

Comment: @CWeeks . . . I don't understand your comment.  Your question is about how to calculate the ratio/percentage.

Answer (score 1):

To simply get the ratio as a percentage you can just do

```
select Sum(case when price<10 then 1.0 end)/Count(*) * 100 as PercentLessThanTen
from t
```

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This can also be written without case which might be useful if you need more categories

```
select sum(c1), sum(c2), sum(c1)*100/sum(c2) as 'ratio' from
(
  select count(*) as c1, 0 as c2 from t where price < 10
  union all
  select 0 as c1, count(*) as c2 from t c1
) counts
```