# Select a column with different status condition in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my output I got two count values based on the condition.

```
SELECT count(distinct sc.staff),
       count(distinct sc.subgroupId) 
FROM schedules sc
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM schedulegroup sg
              WHERE sg.groupid = 15
              AND sc.subgroupId = sg.subgroup 
              AND sg.created BETWEEN '2022-06-01' AND '2022-06-12' 
              AND sc.status IN(1,2)
              )
```

Now I got the result based on the status condition(Status = 1 and 2).
But I need a column of total count without checking the status condition. How to get the count of total records in the existing query?

Comment: The condition is status = 1 OR 2

Comment: the first two counts i need to check the status 1  AND 2.The next count  I want the total count without checking status.

Comment: Please provide example data for the two tables, demonstrating the structure and behaviour of your data. Then, include the results you'd expect for that example data. Please read : [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: Total count of distinct sc.subgroupId or distinct sc.staff or of sc.subgroupId or of sc.staff

Comment: When using MySQL, use [Window Function Concepts and Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html), or if you use  MSSQL, the description is: [SELECT - OVER Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)  and check [How to get multiple counts with one SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12789493/724039)

Comment: Now I got the count of distinct staff and distinct subgroup.I want the count of total records count(sc.id)  without checking status

Comment: And your database is ?

Comment: my databse is postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use combination of count with case when then end.

```
SELECT count(distinct case when sc.status in (1, 2) then sc.staff end),
       count(distinct case when sc.status in (1, 2) then sc.subgroupId end),
       count(sc.id)
FROM schedules sc
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM schedulegroup sg
              WHERE sg.groupid = 15
              AND sc.subgroupId = sg.subgroup 
              AND sg.created BETWEEN '2022-06-01' AND '2022-06-12')
```

[Here is a small demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=060ff264af56a234ec94a6671d67df90)

Comment: Its working.I have one more doubt this query(Sub query) makes any loading issue.In our production db contain around 50k records.

Comment: If the answer is correct I am happy and it would be nice from you to accept it like correct answer and maybe even upvote. Then I suggest to ask a new questions regarding that problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to select the existing data for each `schedule`, *and also* select the total (i.e. without the `status` filter) number of matching `schedulegroup` rows for each `schedule`.

If so, this should do it:

```sql
SELECT count(distinct sc.staff),
       count(distinct sc.subgroupId),
       count(
           SELECT *
              FROM schedulegroup sg
              WHERE sg.groupid = 15
              AND sc.subgroupId = sg.subgroup 
              AND sg.created BETWEEN '2022-06-01' AND '2022-06-12'
       )
FROM schedules sc
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM schedulegroup sg
              WHERE sg.groupid = 15
              AND sc.subgroupId = sg.subgroup 
              AND sg.created BETWEEN '2022-06-01' AND '2022-06-12' 
              AND sc.status IN(1,2)
              )
```

Or do you want to add the non-`status`-filtered `count(distinct sc.staff)` and `count(distinct sc.subgroupId)`, rather than just the row count? If so, you could duplicate the new subquery above and modify it for each `count(distinct ...)` that you want to return.

You could probably make this cleaner (less  repetitive) with a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) or a user-defined function.

Comment: This answer is not working perfectly